Ansible Playbook Not retaining "locale" settings: LC_ALL and LANG empty
I'm experiencing an issue with Ansible playbook where the locale settings do not seem to be retained on the target host. I'm running a playbook with task that will register as output a date. It used to be in this long format: October 20 2045 1:18:21 PM, from one moment on the date turned into 2045 10 20 13:18:21 GMT+02:00 and the next task fails as it is a cast to date with specific pattern.
Then I created another task to see what will be the output:
    - name: show locale settings
      ansible.builtin.shell: 
        cmd: locale
      register: locale_otput  
      tags:
        - inquire

The output from the target host is:
    LANG=
    LC_CTYPE=C.UTF-8
    LC_NUMERIC="POSIX"
    LC_TIME="POSIX"
    LC_COLLATE="POSIX"
    LC_MONETARY="POSIX"
    LC_MESSAGES="POSIX"
    LC_PAPER="POSIX"
    LC_NAME="POSIX"
    LC_ADDRESS="POSIX"
    LC_TELEPHONE="POSIX"
    LC_MEASUREMENT="POSIX"
    LC_IDENTIFICATION="POSIX"
    LC_ALL=

When I manually login to host1 and execute "locale" the output:
`LANG=en_US.ISO-8859-1
LC_CTYPE=en_US.ISO-8859-1
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.ISO-8859-1"
LC_TIME="en_US.ISO-8859-1"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.ISO-8859-1"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.ISO-8859-1"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.ISO-8859-1"
LC_PAPER="en_US.ISO-8859-1"
LC_NAME="en_US.ISO-8859-1"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.ISO-8859-1"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.ISO-8859-1"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.ISO-8859-1"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.ISO-8859-1"
LC_ALL=`

Then I switched the job in AAP to another host2 the output of the same job (AAP) is:
`LANG=en_US.utf8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.utf8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.utf8"
LC_TIME="en_US.utf8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.utf8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.utf8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.utf8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.utf8"
LC_NAME="en_US.utf8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.utf8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.utf8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.utf8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.utf8"
LC_ALL=en_US.utf8`

And when login and local:
`LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
`

On host2 the date is in the long format (as I need it to be) and the task is successful.
I tried to set environment in the task on host1:
    environment:
       LANG: en_US.utf8
       LC_ALL: en_US.utf8

And it works, the date again is October 20 2045 1:18:21 PM, but this is not a proper solution to me, as some other issue can appear is ansible gets those POSIX/empty locale settings.
Why the two outputs differs and could a patching from 7.9 to 8.8 make this happen? What can I do to make sure the locale are the same.

The host1 is "Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8.8 (Ootpa)"
The host2 is "Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7.9 (Maipo)"
Ansible Automation Platform Controller 4.5.1

Thank you.

The locales are based on environment variables.
For example, see how the LANG changes in the output if I set it explicitely:
% locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=sv_SE.UTF-8
LC_TIME=sv_SE.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=sv_SE.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=sv_SE.UTF-8
LC_NAME=sv_SE.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=sv_SE.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=sv_SE.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=sv_SE.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=sv_SE.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
% LANG=en_GB.UTF-8 locale
LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=sv_SE.UTF-8
LC_TIME=sv_SE.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=sv_SE.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=sv_SE.UTF-8
LC_NAME=sv_SE.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=sv_SE.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=sv_SE.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=sv_SE.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=sv_SE.UTF-8
LC_ALL=

When you log in, bash loads several files, for example /etc/profile and ~/.bashrc. So you locales are set in those files and that is why you get that behavior when you log in. Ansible doesn't load those files, so it will use the defaults. My best guess is, that there might have been locales set in /etc/environment (which is loaded for every process, not only shells) and those got removed.
If you depend on specific locales, I would suggest to set them explicitly using environment (as you did). Then you can be sure you use the correct locales and are not dependent on presets on the system which, as you can see, may change and break your playbook.
Also, ansible will complain if you try to use a non-UTF-8 locale.
And I don't know what you are doing, but I guess there might be a better way than parsing a date from a string. Maybe you can directly get a date-object? But that is a different topic.
